# Does mgo supports latest version of mongodb?

Tags: go, mgo

I am trying with mongo 3.4 but refuse to connect server error received. But same code is work with mongodb 2.2 version

Comment: [Not yet](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/pull/394).

Comment: To clarify [mgo.V2](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/tree/v2) supports _connecting_ to MongoDB v3.4. Although there are few outstanding features to support, you should be able to connect without an issue. Post the error message and your code that you'd expect to work.

Comment: @WanBachtiar thanks you are right mgo.v2 works fine with mongodb3.4 may be there is some issue with my code

Comment: What is a current status of this answer?

Comment: @AbhayGawade ya, mgo.v2 works fine with MongoDB 3.4. something was wrong with my code.